# Adding button(Imageview) to viewpager within sliding image activity

Tags: android-layout, menu, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I am relatively new to Android development, my background being more php, html5 and the likes. I've studied, continue to take tutorials and am working on my first application which I've practically got the way I want it to be, save one particular item. I hope that you can help me, and to some, it is likely a simple response. But, I've tried and tried and cannot get things to work out without errors.

Basically, the application uses ViewPager, and has SlidingImageActivity as a class, so when images are loaded in full size (clicked from thumbnail) the images can be swiped from screen to screen.

I have action bar items, which rather than show in the overflow bar, I've created Image Button and placed in the xml below for the viewpager. It is the file - fullimageslider.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/grid_back_color"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/image_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/menu_zoom"
    android:background="@color/grid_back_color" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/grid_back_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/save"
    android:title="@string/menu_save" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu_setaswallpaper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/grid_back_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/set"
    android:title="@string/menu_setaswallpaper" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu_zoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_share"
    android:background="@color/grid_back_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/zoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_zoom" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_setaswallpaper"
    android:background="@color/grid_back_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/share"
   android:title="@string/menu_share" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I've added the buttons as you can see, below the viewpager. So that they remain on the bottom of the layout as the screen swipes.

My problem is, getting the buttons to function in the SlideImageActivity class. I'm not sure where to change the overflow menu tasks to the button tasks. I have removed the items I've created buttons for from the menu. And changed them into the above.

The following is the current SlideImageActivity class.

```
public class SlideImageActivity extends SherlockActivity
implements sensorEventListener {

int position;
String[] mAllImages,mAllImageCatName;

public DatabaseHandler db;
ImageView vp_imageview;
ViewPager viewpager;
int TOTAL_IMAGE;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private boolean checkImage = false;
private long lastUpdate;
Handler handler;
Runnable Update;
boolean Play_Flag=false;
private Menu menu;
private DatabaseManager dbManager;
String  Image_catName,Image_Url;
  Bitmap bgr;
  DisplayImageOptions options;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullimageslider);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    dbManager = DatabaseManager.INSTANCE;
    dbManager.init(getApplicationContext());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
    .build();

 setTitle(Constant.CATEGORY_TITLE);
 // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.


Intent i=getIntent();
position=i.getIntExtra("POSITION_ID", 0);
mAllImages=i.getStringArrayExtra("IMAGE_ARRAY");
mAllImageCatName=i.getStringArrayExtra("IMAGE_CATNAME");


 TOTAL_IMAGE=mAllImages.length-1;
 viewpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
 handler=new Handler();

 ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
 viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
 viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

 sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();


 viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
            Image_Url=mAllImages[position];

            List<Pojo> pojolist=db.getFavRow(Image_Url);
            if(pojolist.size()==0)
            {
                 menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));
            }
            else
            {   
                if(pojolist.get(0).getImageurl().equals(Image_Url))
                {
menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_hover));
                }

}               


 }

 @Override
 public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

 @Override
 public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
 });



 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.photo_menu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    //for when 1st item of view pager is favorite mode
    FirstFav();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
 {       
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
    {
    case android.R.id.home: 
        onBackPressed();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_back:

        position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
        position--;
        if (position < 0) {
            position = 0;
        }
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

        return true;

    case R.id.menu_next:

     position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
          position++;
        if (position == TOTAL_IMAGE) {
            position = TOTAL_IMAGE;
        }
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

    return true;    

    case R.id.menu_play:

        if(Play_Flag)
        {
            handler.removeCallbacks(Update);
            menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
            Play_Flag=false;
            ShowMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * when Play_Flag false then Play
             * but when image is last not start auto play
             * now hide all menu when auto play start
             */
            if(viewpager.getCurrentItem()==TOTAL_IMAGE)
            {

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                AutoPlay();
                menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop));
                Play_Flag=true;
                HideMenu();
            }

        }
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_fav:

        position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();

        Image_Url=mAllImages[position];

        List<Pojo> pojolist=db.getFavRow(Image_Url);
        if(pojolist.size()==0)
        {
AddtoFav(position);//if size is zero i.e means that record not in database show 
add to favorite 
        }
        else
        {   
            if(pojolist.get(0).getImageurl().equals(Image_Url))
            {
                RemoveFav(position);
            }

        }

        return true;    

    case R.id.menu_overflow:
        //just override click 
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_share:

        position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();

(new ShareTask(SlideImageActivity.this)).execute
(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY+mAllImageCatName[position]
+"/"+mAllImages[position]);


        return true;    

    case R.id.menu_save:

        position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();

        (new SaveTask(SlideImageActivity.this)).execute
(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY+mAllImageCatName[position]
+"/"+mAllImages[position]);

        return true;

    case R.id.menu_setaswallaper:

position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
Intent intwall=new intent(getApplicationContext(), SetAsWallpaperActivity.class);
        intwall.putExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_URL", mAllImages);
        intwall.putExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_CATEGORY", mAllImageCatName);
        intwall.putExtra("POSITION_ID", position);
        startActivity(intwall);

        return true;

    case R.id.menu_zoom:
        position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
        Intent intzoom=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PinchZoom.class);
        intzoom.putExtra("ZOOM_IMAGE_URL", mAllImages);
        intzoom.putExtra("ZOOM_IMAGE_CATEGORY", mAllImageCatName);
        intzoom.putExtra("POSITION_ID", position);
        startActivity(intzoom);

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

}

//add to favorite 

public void AddtoFav(int position)
{

    Image_catName=mAllImageCatName[position];
    Image_Url=mAllImages[position];

db.AddtoFavorite(new Pojo(Image_catName, Image_Url));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Added to Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_hover));
}

//remove from favorite
public void RemoveFav(int position)
{
Image_Url=mAllImages[position];
db.RemoveFav(new Pojo(Image_Url));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed from
Favorite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));

}


//auto play slide show

public void AutoPlay()
{
    Update=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AutoPlay();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
              position++;
            if (position == TOTAL_IMAGE) {
                position = TOTAL_IMAGE;
     handler.removeCallbacks(Update);//when last image play mode goes to       Stop
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Last Image Auto Play Stoped",
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     menu.getItem(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
     Play_Flag=false;
     //Show All Menu when Auto Play Stop
    ShowMenu();
            }
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(Update, 1500);
}

public void ShowMenu()
{
     menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
     menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
     menu.getItem(3).setVisible(true);
     menu.getItem(4).setVisible(true);
}

public void HideMenu()
{
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(3).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(4).setVisible(false);
}

public void FirstFav()
{
    int first=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
    String Image_id=mAllImages[first];

    List<Pojo> pojolist=db.getFavRow(Image_id);
    if(pojolist.size()==0)
    {
         menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav));

    }
    else
    {   
        if(pojolist.get(0).getImageurl().equals(Image_id))
        {
menu.getItem(3).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_hover));

        }

    }
}
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImagePagerAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

     @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mAllImages.length;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
assert imageLayout != null;
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
final ProgressBar spinner =(ProgressBar)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);     
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault
(getApplicationContext()));
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY
+mAllImageCatName[position]+"/"+mAllImages[position], imageView, options, new
SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason
 failReason) {
                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(SlideImageActivity.this, message,
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
         ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
  }

 @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }


 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
          getAccelerometer(event);
        }

}
 private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
        float[] values = event.values;
        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
        {
          if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
            return;
          }
          lastUpdate = actualTime;
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Device was shuffed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                .show();
          if (checkImage) {


              position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
              viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);


          } else {

              position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
              position++;
            if (position == TOTAL_IMAGE) {
                position = TOTAL_IMAGE;
            }
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
          }
          checkImage = !checkImage;
        }
      }


      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
        // accelerometer sensors
        if(dbManager == null){
            dbManager = DatabaseManager.INSTANCE;
            dbManager.init(getApplicationContext());
            }else if(dbManager.isDatabaseClosed()){
            dbManager.init(getApplicationContext());
            }
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        // unregister listener
        super.onPause();
        if(!dbManager.isDatabaseClosed())
            dbManager.closeDatabase();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
      }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
             handler.removeCallbacks(Update);
             sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             if(dbManager != null)dbManager.closeDatabase();

        }   





        public class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>
        {
            private Context context;
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            String image_url;
            URL myFileUrl;
            String myFileUrl1;
            Bitmap bmImg = null;
            File file ;


            public SaveTask(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {  

                    myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                    //myFileUrl1 = args[0];

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
    myFileUrl.openConnection();   
                    conn.setDoInput(true);   
                    conn.connect();     
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {       
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
                try {       

                    String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
                    String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/EC Images/");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    String fileName = idStr;
                    file = new File(dir, fileName);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);   
                    fos.flush();    
                    fos.close();    

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                return null;   
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(SlideImageActivity.this, "Image Saved Succesfully /",
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

public class ShareTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>
        {
            private Context context;
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            String image_url;
            URL myFileUrl;
            String myFileUrl1;
            Bitmap bmImg = null;
            File file ;

            public ShareTask(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {  

                    myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                    //myFileUrl1 = args[0];

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();   
                    conn.setDoInput(true);   
                    conn.connect();     
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {       
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
                try {       

                    String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
                    String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/HD Wallpaper/");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    String fileName = idStr;
                    file = new File(dir, fileName);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);   
                    fos.flush();    
                    fos.close();    

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                return null;   
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }       

}
```

As you can see the code implements the menu items, Share, Set as Wallpaper, Save and Zoom. These are the Imagebuttons I -want- to use and have set up on the above xml layout.

This is what I have for the buttons. But I have no idea where or how to add this, implement it into the ImageSliderActivity class.

```
 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_share);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
 (new shareTask(SlideImageActivity.this)).execute(Constant.
 SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY+
 mAllImageCatName[position]+"/"+mAllImages[position]);
 return true;   


 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_save);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
 newSaveTask(SlideImageActivity.this)).execute(Constant.SERVER_IMAGE_UPFOLDER_CATEGORY
 +mAllImageCatName[position]+"/"+mAllImages[position]);
 return true;

 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_setaswallpaper);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
 Intent intwall=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SetAsWallpaperActivity.class);
 intwall.putExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_URL", mAllImages);
 intwall.putExtra("WALLPAPER_IMAGE_CATEGORY", mAllImageCatName);
 intwall.putExtra("POSITION_ID", position);
 startActivity(intwall);
 return true;

 Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_zoom);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 position=viewpager.getCurrentItem();
 Intent intzoom=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PinchZoom.class);
 intzoom.putExtra("ZOOM_IMAGE_URL", mAllImages);
 intzoom.putExtra("ZOOM_IMAGE_CATEGORY", mAllImageCatName);
 intzoom.putExtra("POSITION_ID", position);
 startActivity(intzoom);
 return true;`
```

I hope I've made sense.If some one could please guide me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate the help. Basically, I want to remove the overflow menu during the slidingimage activity, and use buttons at the bottom of the layout instead to implement those items. The layout works in the emulator and causes no error, but obviously when the buttons are clicked, nothing happens because I don't know where to add the button portion to the sliding activity class, without causing multiple errors.

Thanks so much for your time in advance!

Comment: I have actually figured the issue out -- the viewpager wouldn't accept the buttons as ImageButton, but as Button. I changed the button code I have using the Public void, onClick, and placed these under the onCreate (Bundle etc.) The icons are displayed and image buttons function. Everything else still functions in the actionbar except the "play" which when clicked would slide the images as a slide show. The next and previous icons work, so you can scroll through full size images that way, but the play isn't functioning, so that is an error I will have to look into.